# How to make Google Analytics report referrals from sites promoting our site?

Tags: google-analytics

My company has a new partner that is promoting us on their site.  It is a much larger site than ours (much more traffic).   Google Analytics doesn't report a single referral from them.  We know this is not possible because we've had people tell us they found us from our parnter's site.  We also tested the links and they all work correctly - these should at least show up as referral hits.

We seem to be getting data from other traffic sources (although now I'm beginning to question whether there are others we're missing as well).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this question on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try this: Clear your browser cookies, click from their site to yours, and then inspect your cookies. The values in the _utmz cookies should contain the referral information. Otherwise, something is breaking the referral, like a redirect done before the google tracking code, or a redirect from http://example.com to http://www.example.com (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they are not doing redirects?  Put your mouse over the links on their site; is the url your site or a link on their site (in which case they are doing re-directs).

Often times referring sites will use redirects so they in turn can track how often people are clicking the links.